# python capture sys.stdout and sys.exit produced by other module

Tags: python, output, capture, sys

I have two scripts as below but I can not modify foo.py
I have wrote code in bar.py to capture output produced by foo.py so I can modify the output before outputting it to terminal.

But, capture does not work. What am I doing wrong?

```
foo.py
----
import sys


def some_func():
    sys.stdout.write("hello")
    sys.stdout.flush()


def foo():
    some_func()
    sys.exit(1)
```

this is my module I can modify:

```
bar.py
----

import io
from contextlib import redirect_stdout
from foo import foo



f = io.StringIO()
with redirect_stdout(f):
    foo()
s = f.getvalue()
print(s)
```

EDIT:

final solution

```
import io
from contextlib import redirect_stdout
from foo import foo


def capture_output(func):
    f = io.StringIO()
    try:
        with redirect_stdout(f):
            func()
    except SystemExit:
        return f.getvalue()


capture_output(foo)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the call to [`sys.exit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exit) in `foo.py`.

When you call `foo()` in `bar.py`, and then get to the last line of the `foo()` function, the interpreter exits immediately and the rest of `bar.py` after the call to `foo()` isn't executed.  So you *are* capturing stdout properly -- it just isn't printed before the program exits.

If the file you can't change actually does contain a direct call to `sys.exit(1)` and you want to handle it without exiting, you could wrap the call to `foo()` in a `try`/`except` block.  However, depending on the context in which `sys.exit(1)` is actually called, it may make more sense to handle it using something like [`sys.excepthook`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.excepthook)

### Edit:

re: your comments below,

1. if the output can potentially be going to either `sys.stdout` or `sys.stderr`, you should account for either.  E.g., you could do:

   ```py
   from contextlib import redirect_stdout, redirect_stderr


   tmp_stdout, tmp_stderr = StringIO(), StringIO()

   with redirect_stdout(tmp_stdout), redirect_stderr(tmp_stderr):
       foo()

   tmp_stdout, tmp_stderr = tmp_stdout.getvalue(), tmp_stderr.getvalue()
   ```
2. Yes -- `sys.exit()` raises [`SystemExit`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/exceptions.html#SystemExit), so you could potentially do:

   ```py
   try:
       # your code here
   except SystemExit:
       pass
   ```

   although this feels somewhat sketchy to me.  Usually a non-zero exit code indicates something went wrong somewhere in the program, so `sys.exit(1)` being intentionally raised is probably not something you want to suppress silently in the vast majority of cases.

Comment: I can not modify foo and this is what i am trying to capture https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/ae50d0518223bb5f261d024eaf79f42304cdca44/lib/ansible/utils/display.py#L284

Comment: is there a way to capture sys.exit called in other module and actualy not exit but handle it?

Answer (score 1):

This is what you could try:

```
import sys
import os
import importlib

# foo.py

def some_func():
    sys.stdout.write("hello")
    sys.stdout.flush()


def foo():
    some_func()
    sys.exit(1)


# bar.py

original = sys.stdout

def start_capture():
    sys.stdout = open('tmpfile', 'w')

def stop_capture():
    sys.stdout.close()
    sys.stdout = original
    data = ""
    with open('tmpfile', 'r') as f:
        data = f.read()
    os.remove('tmpfile')
    return data


start_capture()
try:
    foo()
except SystemExit:
    print('\nFoo Exit!\n')
print(stop_capture())
```

For demo purpose i put the foo.py in same file but the main part is redirecting the stdout

Comment: thank you for the code as it does the job so I appreciate your contribution but actualy @paxton4416 suits better my needs.